# Improve speed of SQL (lite) query for inner join

Tags: sql, performance, sqlite

I have the following query which is running a very long time > 30 min and I would like to know if there are some ways to improve the performance.

The script is executed through Python (3.X)

Goal of join is to fill table FinalUS with details of vehicles from US_vehicles.

Explanation of table design

- FinalUS contains vehicles with one single vin-number (Vehicle identification number)
- US_vehicles contains details to vehicles to which multiple vins are assigned (separated by comma)

Measures taken already:

- vin-column (separated by comma) was decluttered into vin1-vin34
- Index on all columns that need to match
- used IN instead of LIKE

Table info:

- FinalUS: contains 99740 rows
- US_vehicles: contains 62865 rows

.

```
INSERT INTO mergenhtsaed 
            (COMMENT,                 finalusid, 
             edmundsids,              addvin, 
             length,                  height, 
             widthnomirror,           bedlength, 
             bedlengthstd,            doors, 
             torqueprimary,           torqueprimaryrpm, 
             horsepowerrpmprimary,    transtypestd, 
             transspeed,              transtypestddetail, 
             drivenwheels,            cafecarlineclass, 
             wheelbase,               fronttrack, 
             reartrack,               primaryfuelstd, 
             horsepowerprimary,       hybrid, 
             flexfuel,                bodystyle) 
SELECT "1:", 
       FU.id, 
       Group_concat(DISTINCT UV.id), 
       Group_concat(DISTINCT squishvins), 
       Round(Avg(UV.overall_length), 1), 
       Round(Avg(UV.overall_height), 1), 
       Round(Avg(UV.overall_width_without_mirrors), 1), 
       Round(Avg(bedlength), 1), 
       Round(Avg(bedsizestdft), 1), 
       Group_concat(DISTINCT UV.numofdoors), 
       Round(Avg(UV.engine_torque)), 
       Round(Avg(UV.engine_rpm_torque)), 
       Round(Avg(UV.engine_rpm_horsepower)), 
       UV.transtypestd, 
       UV.transspeed, 
       UV.transtypestddetail, 
       UV.drivenwheelsstd, 
       Group_concat(DISTINCT uv .` categories_epaclass ` ), 
       Round(Avg(UV.wheelbase), 1), 
       Round(Avg(UV.front_track), 1), 
       Round(Avg(UV.rear_track), 1), 
       Group_concat(DISTINCT UV.primaryfuelstd), 
       Round(Avg(UV.engine_horsepower)), 
       Group_concat(DISTINCT UV.hybrid), 
       Group_concat(DISTINCT UV.flexfuel), 
       Group_concat(DISTINCT UV.bodystyle) 
FROM   finalus FU 
inner join us_vehicles UV 
        ON UV.years_year = FU.modelyear 
       AND fu .` vin ` IN ( UV.vin1, UV.vin2, UV.vin3, UV.vin4, 
                            UV.vin5, UV.vin6, UV.vin7, UV.vin8, 
                            UV.vin9, UV.vin10, UV.vin11, UV.vin12, 
                            UV.vin13, UV.vin14, UV.vin15, UV.vin16, 
                            UV.vin17, UV.vin18, UV.vin19, UV.vin20, 
                            UV.vin21, UV.vin22, UV.vin23, UV.vin24, 
                            UV.vin25, UV.vin26, UV.vin27, UV.vin28, 
                            UV.vin29, UV.vin30, UV.vin31, UV.vin32, 
                            UV.vin33, UV.vin34 ) 
WHERE FU.modelyear < 2012 
  AND FU.edmundsid IS NULL 
  AND FU.dataoneid IS NULL 
GROUP  BY FU.id 
HAVING Count(DISTINCT UV.id) = 1
```

Explain query plan

```
Selectid|order|from|detail        
"0"|"0"|"0"|"SEARCH TABLE FinalUS AS FU USING INDEX Idx3 (EdmundsId=?)"
"0"|"1"|"1"|"SCAN TABLE US_Vehicles AS UV"
```

Comment: performance question should include [**explain plan**](https://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) with description of tables size and index

Comment: Your query is pretty hopeless because of the arcane `join`.  Storing values across rows in columns can doom performance.

Comment: @GordonLinoff could you explain it in more detail how to improve it. I have the UV.vin1-UV.vin34 in one column and separated by a "," but the performance is not better.I decluttered the vins as I thought it might be faster.

Comment: your problem is not with this query, it's with your database design. A 34 column table always smells of being unnormalized

Comment: Please check my updated posting.@e4c5 what is your recommendation?

Comment: Move vins to separate table. Clear the data, are duplicate vins allowed? If not, make them unique. Get rid of the grouping and the DISTINCTs. Make the query simple.